# error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_41.lib'

Tags: boost

I am getting this error when i am compiling my project under VS2012. It is looking for boost library made in VS2010. I want to use 2012 library. I build the boost with 2012 and found that with 2012, it is generating only 80 files and 2010 it is more than 150 files.

Found that it is doing this auto link from header file. Where is it taking this header file from? Why it is not using the 2012 files which is available? The last build of boost was with 2012 and all the paths are pointing to 2012 files. I removed all 2010 files also.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that everything component you are trying to link has been rebuilt using VS2012 and that there are no projects lurking that are being built with the v100 toolchain? That would be the most likely scenario to trigger this behaviour.

Make sure that all your projects have actually been upgraded to use VS2012 and that you don't have a VS2010 project in your solution.

Comment: The solution i am trying have only one project. It was in 2010 and i converted it when it asked for it. Still trying to use the 2010 version

Comment: Which toolset / toolchain is it set up for?

Comment: --toolset=msvc-11.0. Boost was built like this. Tried all that i can and still it wants to use the old lib.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, my question was which toolset you have set up in Visual Studio for your project - you can use either the VS2010 or the VS2012 compiler from VS2012's IDE so you need to make sure that you have set up the correct compiler

Comment: It is VS2012.  Found the issue. The boost 1_41 uses only upto MS2010. Any MSVC version above it, it assumes that it is MS2010. Added one more condition in boost header file and all is working fine.

Comment: That makes sense. I would however suggest you update Boost - 1.41 is really, really old (1.53 is the current release).

Comment: Main change was in boost\config\auto_link.hpp. Thanks. We will update to 1.53